# Angular Library - Nested component error - 'X' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have the following Angular 10 library:

```
projects/
       my-lib/
             app-lib.component.ts
             app-lib.module.ts
             toolbar/
                    toolbar.component.ts
```

my abbreviated module library

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
AppLibComponent,
ToolbarComponent],
exports: [
    AppLibComponent,
    ToolbarComponent
  ]
})
export class AppLibModule { }
```

The AppLibComponent.html uses the toolbar:

```
<lib-toolbar></lib-toolbar>
<div>main content</div>
```

I push this library to my local Artifactory and use it in another Angular project.

The main abbreviated module looks like this:

```
import { AppLibComponent } from 'app-lib';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppLibComponent
  ],
})

export class AppModule { }
```

The app.component.html :

```
<app-lib></app-lib>
```

When I run this, the app renders the main content of the library

```
<div>main content</div>
```

but gives me the following error for the toolbar component:

```
core.js:14085 'lib-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'lib-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'lib-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

That makes no sense since I declare the toolbar component in the AppLibModule. What I am missing?

Additionally, when I debug the source code in Chrome debugger, I can see that the ToolbarComponent is present.

The library works fine when tested with the same project using a path in tsconfig.json pointing to the build in dist/app-lib.
It only fails when published to the repo and thereafter imported.

Is it possible to use a child component in an Angular library?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem in an Angular 14 application